# How to configure to run SQUID on Windows?

Tags: windows, proxy, squid

How can i implement to get working SQUID Server on Windows? I got squid-3.0.STABLE23 Binary with Zipped version. But when i run sbin/squid from `Command Prompt`, it showing configuration errors. I don't know how to configure.

Is is the right place to start Squid (or) where should i start to run Squid?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're better off running it under http://www.cygwin.com/ emulation. If you've already tried compiling it for native running, then at least try this. It's less prone to cause errors with Squid.

Comment: Running it under Cygwin ? uh..